# Detecting Nested Shape in opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, contour, opencv

I need to detect a nested shape in opencv, but it seems like I can do it even using the hierarchy

---

```
edges = cv2.Canny(img,50,200)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

hierarchy = hierarchy[0] # get the actual inner list of hierarchy descriptions


for comp in contours:

currentCont = comp[0]
currentHie = hierarchy[1]

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(currentContour)
  if ( currentHierarchy[1] < 0 ) 
    these are the innermost child components
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),3)
    cv2.putText(img, "nes", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [currentCont], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.imshow("image",img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Not quite sure how you are getting to the 'innermost child components'. Once you have the top level hierarchy of, say a rectangle, and a successful test of it, you then need to find if the child of the child (a foreground) contour of that rectangle contour is a triangle or not. Once that test is successful you have a nested shape of a triangle within a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to show you how to find the most inner contours that are also nested.
I case there are more complex formations than your sample, you will have to sort it out.

- I suggest not using `cv2.Canny`, because it creates more hierarchies.
  Take a look using `cv2.imshow("edges", edges)` and `cv2.waitKey()`.
  You may just invert polarity to get white triangles on black background.

  ```
   img = 255 - img
  ```
- There is a small bug (inside the loop):
  You are using: `currentHierarchy = hierarchy[1]`
  Instead of: `currentHierarchy = component[1]`

Finding the nested contours:

- Start from the most inner contours.
  The most inner contours are contours with no "first child".
  Check if `currentHierarchy[2] < 0`.
- All the inner contours are going to have a parent contour.
  The reason for that is that each triangle applies two (nested) contours:

  - An inner contour in the inner edge of the triangle.
  - An outer contour in the outer edge of the triangle.

  We need to get the parent contour, and **check if the parent has a parent**.
  Inner triangles that have a grandparent are nested triangles.

Here is the complete code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('triangles.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read input image as grayscale,

# edges = cv2.Canny(img, 50, 200)

# Invert polarity of img, instead of using Canny - we need the contours to be white.
img = 255 - img

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

hierarchy = hierarchy[0] # get the actual inner list of hierarchy descriptions

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) # Convert image to BGR, for using colored text.

for component in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    currentContour = component[0]
    #currentHierarchy = hierarchy[1] # Why ?
    currentHierarchy = component[1]

    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(currentContour, 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(currentContour, True), True)
    x = approx.ravel()[0]
    y = approx.ravel()[1] - 5

    # https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html
    # Hierarchy Representation in OpenCV
    # Each contour has its own information regarding what hierarchy it is, who is its child, who is its parent etc. 
    # OpenCV represents it as an array of four values : [Next, Previous, First_Child, Parent]

    #if (currentHierarchy[1] < 0) and len(approx) == 3:

    if (currentHierarchy[2] < 0) and len(approx) == 3:
        # These are the innermost child components

        parent_idx = currentHierarchy[3]  # Get the index of the parent contour
        parent_hier = hierarchy[parent_idx]  # Get the hierarchy of the parent.

        if parent_hier[3] >= 0:
            # Contour is nested only if the parent has a parent.
            cv2.putText(img, "Nested", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.drawContours(img, [currentContour], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
            cv2.waitKey(1000)
            cv2.imshow("image", img)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: The problem with this code is that it even detect a triangle as a nested triangle if it is inside another shape like a circle, square or rectangular. I can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

Usecases: If the triangle is inside another shape like square, circle, or rectangular it should not detect it as a nested triangle. until unless there are two triangles inside.

Here are the images for testing:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Zhr.png](Image 1)
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0p78.png](Image 2)

Comment: Traverse the contours from the grandparent up the hierarchy, (get the index of the parent contour from the hierarchy). When you have the index, get the contour that matches the index: `contours[index]` gives you the contour. Check if the contour is a triangle `len(approx) == 3`... Keep going up getting the parents, until the value is `-1`. If one of the parents is a triangle, you have a nested triangle.